# Magic 8 ball in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am thinking of making a "magic 8 ball" kind of website. I would like a version of the following code that looks more like [the helix fossil website](https://askhelixfossil.com/).

```js
var answers = [ 
  'Maybe.', 'Certainly not.', 'I hope so.', 'Not in your wildest dreams.',
  'There is a good chance.', 'Quite likely.', 'I think so.', 'I hope not.',
  'I hope so.', 'Never!', 'Fuhgeddaboudit.', 'Ahaha! Really?!?', 'Pfft.',
  'Sorry, bucko.', 'Hell, yes.', 'Hell to the no.', 'The future is bleak.',
  'The future is uncertain.', 'I would rather not say.', 'Who cares?',
  'Possibly.', 'Never, ever, ever.', 'There is a small chance.', 'Yes!'];

document.getElementById('answerButton').onclick = function () { 
  var answer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
  document.getElementById('answerContainer').innerHTML = answer;
};
```

```css
p, input, button { 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
} 
input { 
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p> How can I help you today? </p>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter a question"></input>

<button id="answerButton"> Answer me </button>

<p id="answerContainer"></p>
```

Also, when I put this into the "insert code" feature in Weebly, it keeps showing the raw code above the elements. Any way I could clean this up or should I just use a different website creator?

I know nothing about CSS.

Comment: The next time you take code from an existing answer on Stack Overflow, please mention where the code came from and provide a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet that adds some styling to the basic code.

If you want to make a web page out of this, you can put the CSS inside `style` tags, the JavaScript inside `script` tags, and the HTML inside `body` tags.

[Like this: right-click on my page](http://michaellaszlo.com/so/magic-eight-ball/) and select "View Page Source" (or whatever your browser of choice calls it) to see how the page is organized.

Better yet, if the Weebly file manager allows it, put the CSS and JavaScript into external files and link to them in the HTML file.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var answers = [
    'Maybe.', 'Certainly not.', 'I hope so.', 'Not in your wildest dreams.',
    'There is a good chance.', 'Quite likely.', 'I think so.', 'I hope not.',
    'I would say so.', 'Never!', 'Fuhgeddaboudit.', 'Ahaha! Really?!?', 'Pfft.',
    'Sorry, bucko.', 'Hell, yes.', 'Hell to the no.', 'The future is bleak.',
    'The future is uncertain.', 'I would rather not say.', 'Who cares?',
    'Possibly.', 'Never, ever, ever.', 'There is a small chance.', 'Yes!'];

  var container = document.getElementById('answerContainer'),
      opacityPercent,
      previousAnswer;
  function updateOpacity() {
    opacityPercent += 1;
    container.style.opacity = opacityPercent / 100;
    if (opacityPercent < 100) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(updateOpacity);
    }
  }
  function makeVisible() {
    container.style.opacity = '0';
    opacityPercent = -1;
    updateOpacity();
  }
  opacityPercent = -1;
  document.getElementById('questionArea').value = '';
  document.getElementById('answerButton').onclick = function () {
    while (true) {
      var answer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
      if (answers.length == 1 || answer != previousAnswer) {
        previousAnswer= answer;
        break;
      }
    }
    container.className = '';
    container.innerHTML = answer;
    makeVisible();
  };
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #e8e8d6;
  color: #333;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
p, input, button {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#answerContainer {
  opacity: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
}
input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #888;
}
button {
  background: #ffe;
  color: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover {
  background: #ffc;
  color: #222;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">

<div id="wrapper">

<p> What do you want to know about the future? </p>

<p>
  <input id="questionArea" type="text" placeholder="enter a question"></input>
</p>

<p>
  <button id="answerButton"> Make a prediction </button>
</p>

<p id="answerContainer"></p>

</div>
```